# Add custom scrape endpoints in helm chart kube-prometheus-stack deployment

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

First off a little new to using helm...

So I'm struggling to get the helm deployment of this: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

To work the way I would like in my kubernetes cluster. I like what it has done so far but how can I make it scrape a custom endpoint? I have seen this: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus

Under the section titled: "**Scraping Pod Metrics via Annotations**". I have added the following annotations to the pod deployment (and then the node port service) in kubernetes:

```
annotations = {
 "prometheus.io/scrape" = "true"
 "prometheus.io/path"   = "/appMetrics/prometheusMetrics"
 "prometheus.io/port"   = "443"
}
```

However, when I look in the `targets` page of prometheus I don't see it there. I also don't see it in the configuration file. So that makes me think this helm chart isn't deploying the same `prometheus` chart.

So now the question is, how can I setup a custom scrape endpoint using the helm chart `kube-prometheus-stack`. From my reading this is the one I should* be using, right?

Comment: I am doing the same thing as you. I am install kube-prometheus-stack by helm as well. From the prometheus configuration (https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/), it indicates we can add global/rule_files/scrape_config into the prometheus.yml. However, I tried to add those into the values.yaml of helm chart but no luck. Also there is a helm chart called https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus-adapter, not sure whether should use it. (I am doing some research for HPA)

Comment: I have also tried to add the helm exposed values `additionalScrapeConfigsSecret` and `additionalScrapeConfigsSecret` with no luck. It seems like it completely ignores these values. Someone else has actually opened an issue about this here: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/3608

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this below in your custom_values.yaml and apply it.

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
      - job_name: your_job_name
        scrape_interval: 15s
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: pod
          namespaces:
            names:
              - your_namespace
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: pod
        - source_labels: [__address__]
          action: replace
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?
          replacement: ${1}:your_port
          target_label: __address__
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app]
          action: keep
          regex: your_pod_name
```

You need to replace `your_job_name`, `your_namespace`, `your_port`, `your_pod_name` to your deployment file. After I did the above metric and re-install Prometheus by helm chart, now I can see the target, and the metrics get exposed.

Comment: A link to docs or a reference to where this yaml came from would be very helpful. Also any explanation regarding what should go in these values (like `job_name`) would be nice, for those of us who are new to this technology.

Comment: I am also a new bird on this and it's a long time ago.. I can't remember what did I search for that. But you can just google it and there are tons of tips/docs about this part.
e.g. search "prometheus adapter prometheusSpec additionalScrapeConfigs" in google and then start to read.

Comment: @joniba this is a sample reference yaml : https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/release-2.37/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml


Also, documentation for kubernetes_sd_config :  https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config