# Prometheus helm chart custom config

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have applied the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) to my k8s cluster, and notice there are no scrape configs for my services or pods.

I'd like all services etc in my cluster to be scraped, according to the standard k8s attributes e.g.:

```yaml
prometheus.io/path: /metrics
prometheus.io/port: '8080'
prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
```

My question is:

- Is there a supported way to tell the operator to scrape everything? The docs seems to suggest not, so..
- Failing that, is there a place that I can upload some custom prometheus config to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there was already a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452966/add-custom-scrape-endpoints-in-helm-chart-kube-prometheus-stack-deployment)

Just add your additional jobs to the values file at this location:

```yaml
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
      - job_name: some_job
        ...
```